# mssql query to insert and update textbox values

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image: asp page]I have two textboxes in asp page which gets saved in DB on button click. I am in need of query to insert and if values exists, it has to be updated. Could you please find what's wrong with my query and why it's not working?

```
protected void save_returnedmails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(devconnstring);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow g1 in ReturnMailGrid.Rows)
            {
                string reasontxt = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)g1.FindControl("reasontxt")).Text;
                string actiontxt = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)g1.FindControl("actiontxt")).Text;
                string returnmailqry = "if exists(select * from EmailQ_Summary where dscLinkkey='" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "') begin update EmailQ_Summary set Reason='" + reasontxt + "',Action='" + actiontxt + "' where dscLinkkey='" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "' end else begin insert into EmailQ_Summary(dscLinkkey,Reason,Action) values('" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "','" + reasontxt + "','" + actiontxt + "') end";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(returnmailqry, con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            Label1.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally { con.Close(); }
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please also add relevant `tag` as you are using the query in a program seems to be.

Comment: Update is not working. Insert statement works fine.

Comment: What is g1.Cells[2].Text?

Comment: unique key value in gridview, fetched from another DB. I am updating reason and action for those unique keys in my DB. I have to update it intermittently and have to generate report weekly.

Comment: A lot of bugs in this code - using an IF in SQL when the WHERE statement *already* filters by that condition. You are executing *two* searches when one would be enough. You can use WHERE in the INSERT query too, or use MERGE. Using string concatenation instead of parameters. What happens if `reasontxt` contains `Gotcha'; DROP TABLE Users;--` ? You wouldn't get an exception from that query either. Using try/finally instead of `using` and no, `using` isn't the same as try/finally

Comment: Let us know the exact error message. Better test your query in `SSMS`

Comment: thanks for your idea Sir @Md.SumanKabir. It's works fine when reason and action db column values are not null. But on the first instance, if  '','' are inserted into reason & action columns, then its not getting updated. I found this in SSMS.

Comment: Query works fine , but the below mentioned line 
string reasontxt = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)g1.FindControl("reasontxt")).Text;
                is not getting updated text.